# Why do we need to place structure fields in the heap memory?

Tags: c, heap-memory

Consider the following program

```
typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    int id;
}Student;

int main()
{
    Student std1,std2;  //case 1
    std1.name =(char*) malloc(7);
    strcpy(std1.name, "Daniel");
    puts(std1.name);

    char name[7]={'D','a','n','i','e','l','\0'}; //case 2
    std2.name = name;
    puts(std2.name);
}
```

Case 1 place the name of the student in the heap memory while case 2 place the name of student2 in the sack memory, if I understand correctly.

My question is, why would I want to place the name (or any other field of structure) in the heap memory?

Comment: `char name[7]={'D','a','n','i','e','l','\0'};` could be easier written as `char name[7]="Daniel";`

Comment: Data on the stack cannot outlive the function call in which it was created – if it shall, one needs to create it on the heap. Apart from some data might just be too large to be placed on the stack (heap usually is larger).

Comment: `malloc`+`strcpy` can be replaced with `strdup`: `std1.name = strdup("Daniel");`

Comment: @YakovGalka `strdup` is not available on all platforms.

Comment: If you **always** allocate by a fixed amount, like `malloc(7)`, you could just as well put `char name[7]` inside the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Case 2 works for you, by all means use it -- stack memory is faster to allocate, and is deallocated automatically.

You need Case 1 when the memory is too big to be on the stack (e.g. megabytes on typical systems), or it needs to outlive the function you allocate it in. It can typically happen when you allocate the `struct` itself on the heap. E.g.:

```
Student *new_student() {
    Student *p = malloc(sizeof(Student));
    p->id = 0;
    p->name = malloc(7);
    strcpy(p->name, "Daniel");
    return p;
}
```

In this example a stack allocation won't cut it.